# ALternatives to multiple while and if statements

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, try-catch

The state of this. How else can I offer the user multiple levels of options and check that the user inputs the correct value at each level without having to use multiple while loops, try and if statements.

```py
while True:
    try:
        user_choice = int(input("Enter an option 1 or 2"))
        if user_choice == 1 or 2:
            if user_choice = 1:
                while True:
                    try:
                        edit_choice = int(input("Would you like to edit (1) or delete (2)"))
                        if edit_choice == 1 or 2:
                            if edit_choice = 1:
                                \# code to offer more options and more while, try and if statements.
                                break
                            elif edit_choice = 2:
                                \# code to offer more options and more while, try and if statements.
                                break
                        else:
                            print("\\nPlease enter a valid option.")
                    except ValueError:
                        print("\\nPlease enter a number.")
                    break
            elif user_choice = 2:
                \# code to offer more options and more while, try and if statements.
                break
        else:
            print("\\nPlease enter a valid option.")
    except ValueError:
        print("\\nPlease enter a number.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rewrite it using recursive function calls instead of `while` loops like this:

```py
def enter_option():
    try:
        user_choice = int(input("Enter an option 1 or 2: "))
        if user_choice in [1, 2]:
            if user_choice == 1:
                edit_or_delete()
            elif user_choice == 2:
                edit_or_delete()
        else:
            print("\nPlease enter a valid option.")
            enter_option()
    except ValueError:
        print("\nPlease enter a number.")
        enter_option()


def edit_or_delete():
    try:
        edit_choice = int(input("Would you like to edit (1) or delete (2): "))
        if edit_choice in [1, 2]:
            if edit_choice == 1:
                enter_option() # code to offer more options
            elif edit_choice == 2:
                enter_option() # code to offer more options
        else:
            print("\nPlease enter a valid option.")
            edit_or_delete()
    except ValueError:
        print("\nPlease enter a number.")
        edit_or_delete()


enter_option()
```